# How to block a MessageBox with IDA?

Tags: reverse-engineering, cheat-engine

I am using the free version of IDA. I'm trying to change the opcode in a game with Cheat Engine, but the game has blocked it. When I open the game it shows me an error message box and closes the game. What can I do to block this functionality? I think I can do it via cheat engine or IDA.

I did a string search with IDA and Cheat Engine but failed.

Comment: _"I am using the free version of IDA"_ - is that what we're calling it now? ‍☠️ (UPDATE: Apparently [there really is a free version](https://hex-rays.com/ida-free/) of IDA now - huh...)

Comment: _"but the game has blocked it"_ - does the game detect IDA _specifically_, or does it attempt to block any attempt to attach a debugger? Presumably this is in Windows? Can you share any details, like the game title you're looking at?

Comment: The name of the game is Growtopia. I guess the game detects that the opcodes have been changed. For example, when I reverse an opcode address via Cheat Engine, it understands it. Message box error: "File corrupted! This program has been manipulated and maybe it's infected by a Virus or cracked. This file won't work anymore."

Comment: Can someone help please?